# React Native onResponderGrant locationX

Tags: react-native

I have a view that I'm trying to detect tap start and tap release events along the X axis.  Generally it works fine, but tapping down on the same point twice in a row returns a different `locationX` value (at least on iOS, I haven't checked Android).

Here's the first tap event:

```
{ target: 1843,
  pageX: 275.5,
  timestamp: 24045471.998439003,
  locationX: 255.5,
  pageY: 812,
  locationY: 5,
  identifier: 1,
  changedTouches: [ [Circular] ],
  touches: [] }
```

Here's the second tap event, compare the `locationX` values and the `pageX` values

```
{ target: 1842,
  pageX: 275.5,
  timestamp: 24048057.758042004,
  locationX: 5,
  pageY: 812,
  locationY: 5,
  identifier: 1,
  changedTouches: [ [Circular] ],
  touches: [ [Circular] ] }
```

Normally I would just use the tap release (which is correct), but I have drawing that I'm doing to the location of the touch which doesn't work properly because of this issue.

I could also kludge something that uses the `pageX` but I'd rather not go with that approach.

Has anyone else run into this issue or know why it's happening?  It's kind of annoying.  I can't tell if it is a bug or was implemented intentionally.